# How to use copy_to_user

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to add a custom system call into the linux kernel. Here is a simple code:

```c
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/system.h>

asmlinkage int sys_mysyscall(int *data){

    int a = 3;

    cli();
    copy_to_user(data, &a, 1);
    sti();

    printk(KERN_EMERG "Called with %d\n", a);

    return a;
}
```

I can compile a kernel with mysyscall added and when I try to access it with a user program like:

```c
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>

int main(void){

    int *data;
    int r;
    int a = 0;
    data = &a;

    r = mysyscall(data);

    printf("r is %d and data is %d", r, *data);
}
```

*data does not equal to 3 it equals to 0.

How should I use copy_to_user to fix it?

Comment: `copy_to_user(data, &a, sizeof a)` and initialize `data` as a pointer to something?

Comment: I initialized data as a pointer to a variable. However, it shows the variable's old value (I edited the post above).

Comment: I've found the problem. In /usr/include/linux/mysyscall.h file _syscall1(int, mysyscall, int, \*data) line must be _syscall1(int, mysyscall, int\*, data). Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You still need `sizeof` to copy whole `int`. Without it it won't work properly (take `int a = 260` for example).

Comment: What is the output of "printf"? And why "a" is returning while system call should return number of bytes written (sizeof(int))?

Comment: I know. I just want to test it. Now it works fine.

Comment: It may work in some cases now. You are disabling interrupts around the `copy_to_user` call and that is not allowed at all. I fail to see what purpose disabling interrupts could possibly serve there.

Comment: Could you explain that why it is not allowed? I disabled interrupts since I thought that something can intercept the copy operation.

Comment: @yildizabdullah Why would you think that? Interrupts happen all the time, unless you have a specific reason why interrupts shouldn't happen you don't disable them. In this case, the `copy_to_user` may trigger a page fault which may require sleeping for its handling (e.g. when the page isn't in memory and has to be loaded from disk). Sleeping with interrupts disabled is not allowed. That will either Oops right away or just freeze.

Comment: So is it enough to use only `copy_to_user`?

Comment: @yildizabdullah Certainly without meddling with interrupts. However you have to check the return value of `copy_to_user` to know whether there was an error (and if appropriate return the error value to the caller).

Comment: I think you can disable local irq interrupts though..ie those interrupts that only your driver uses and is not shared by any one.
That will ensure race conditions like your data being updated before copy to user can be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

The copy to user line of code copies only one byte from 'a'. In case of little endian systems it is going to be 0. Copy all the 4 bytes to get the correct result.